# Trigger with errors

Tags: database, oracle11g, triggers, sqlplus

I am getting error while creating this trigger. My goal is that if we insert an customer in the customers table, the no.of customers column in the bank table for that bank should get updated.

```
DELIMITER @@
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER USER.bank_trigger AFTER
  INSERT ON customers FOR EACH row BEGIN
  UPDATE bank
  SET no_of_customers = no_of_customers + 1
  WHERE bank_id       = new.bank_id
END @@ DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your tags for Oracle 11g , The `CREATE TRIGGER` syntax you are using is not correct.Here is the correct syntax. `:new` represents the new value of the column inside trigger body.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER bank_trigger AFTER
  INSERT ON customers FOR EACH row 
  BEGIN
  UPDATE bank
  SET no_of_customers = no_of_customers + 1
  WHERE bank_id = :new.bank_id;
END;
/
```